# First faltering step with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, system.reactive

I'm struggling with my first simple "hello world" RX application. I'm using VS2010 RC, plus the latest RX download.

The following is the simple console app;

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var channel = new MessageChannel()
                .Where(m => m.process)
                .Subscribe((MyMessage m) => Console.WriteLine(m.subject));

            //channel.GenerateMsgs();
        }
    }

    public class MyMessage
    {
        public string subject;
        public bool process;
    }

    public class MessageChannel: IObservable<MyMessage>
    {
        List<IObserver<MyMessage>> observers = new List<IObserver<MyMessage>>();

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<MyMessage> observer)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
            return observer as IDisposable;
        }

        public void GenerateMsgs()
        {
            foreach (IObserver<MyMessage> observer in observers)
            {
                observer.OnNext(new MyMessage() {subject = "Hello!", process = true});
            }
        }
    }
```

I get a ArgumentNullException at the Where clause. Here's the stack;

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: disposable
  Source=System.Reactive
  ParamName=disposable
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Generic.AnonymousObservable`1.Disposable.Set(IDisposable disposable)
       at System.Collections.Generic.AnonymousObservable`1.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Subscribe>b__0()
       at System.Threading.Scheduler.NowScheduler.Schedule(Action action)
       at System.Collections.Generic.AnonymousObservable`1.Subscribe(IObserver`1 observer)
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Jason\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems to be causing the fuss:

```
return observer as IDisposable;
```

You are not supposed to assume the the observer is disposable, you are supposed to return a disposable object that knows about "unsubscribing".

> The method returns a reference to an
>   IDisposable interface. This enables
>   the observer to unsubscribe (that is,
>   to stop receiving notifications)
>   before the provider has finished
>   sending them and called the
>   subscriber's OnCompleted method.

You can make it work by doing something like:

```
public class MessageChannel: IObservable<MyMessage>
{
    class Subscription : IDisposable {
        MessageChannel _c;
        IObservable<MyMessage> _obs;
        public Subscription(MessageChannel c, IObservable<MyMessage> obs) { 
            _c = c; _obs = obs;
        }
        public void Dispose() {
            _c.Unsubscribe(_obs);
        }
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<MyMessage> observer)
    {
        observers.Add(observer);
        return new Subscription(this, observer);
    }

    void Unsubscribe(IObservable<MyMessage> obs) {
        observers.Remove(obs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Frank, that hit it on the head. Just needed to change the Subcribe class to use IObserver rather than IObservable (I'm not complaining!). I used the MSDN sample provided on IObserverable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: You could also use `Disposable.Create(() => Unsubscribe(observer))` - the `System.Reactive.Disposables` namespace has a number of useful IDisposable implementations

Answer (score 1):

**!!Red flag!!**

I would strongly suggest that you don't implement `IObserver<T>` or `IObservable<T>` yourself. Favor the use of `Observable.Create<T>` or as a last resort use the `Subject` types. There are lots of things you need to consider to correctly implement these interfaces which is handled for you by the correct Rx types and operators.

In this example I would urge you to drop the MessageChannel type and swap it for

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var channel = GenerateMsgs()
            .Where(m => m.process)
            .Subscribe((MyMessage m) => Console.WriteLine(m.subject));
    }

    public IObservable<MyMessage> GenerateMsgs()
    {
        return Observable.Create<MyMessage>(observer=>
        {
            observer.OnNext(new MyMessage() {subject = "Hello!", process = true});
        });
    }
}

public class MyMessage
{
    public string subject;
    public bool process;
}
```

On further inspection of a system design you may have some sort of Service that exposes "channels" as observable sequences.

```
public interface OrderService
{
    IObservable<OrderRequest> OrderRequests();
    IObservable<Order> ProcessedOrders();
    IObservable<OrderRejection> OrdersRejections();
}
```

Thus negating the need for these custom implementations of `IObserver<T>` or `IObservable<T>`.